# Implementing index.php that serves index.html

Tags: apache-httpd, php

I want a webpage to reflect a log file.  I have a bash script that converts the log to html.  Currently this runs periodically via crontab, which works, but obviously executions are redundant when the webpage isn't viewed.  I'd like to implement a system so the bash script runs only called when the webpage is called.

I gather an index.php script along the lines:

```
<?php
$message=shell_exec(". /path/script.sh");
?>
```

.. should generate the `index.html` file ok.  But is there an easy way to get index.php/Apache to serve that file to the client browser?

Comment: Why not use [a modified version of] your bash script as a CGI instead of a PHP proxy?

Comment: The title does not accurately reflect your question. You are not talking about a static `index.html` file (for which the answer would be some of  linking or redirection).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could use [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) to dump the file you've just created towards the browser. Alternatively, you could issue a 302 temporary redirect to `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

I gather the best solution is to end the php with:

```
header('Location: index.html');
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

Create an `.htaccess` file in your web server root with the following:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```

Now apache will process `.htm` and `.html` files as php documents and any `<?php ... ?>` tags located in that file will be interpreted as php.